# Attempting to add a prefix to a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, prefix

I'm trying to add prefix with a condition using 'from' x table then using where to specify the id

For example:

```
UPDATE tablenameX 
SET columnnameX = 'prefix' + columnnameX 
FROM tablenameY 
WHERE columnnameY = 'id'
```

I really don't see wheres the issue it refuses to read after `columnnameX`, what I mean by that is it would execute with no issue, however it ignores the argument I'm trying to use and it applies to every column entry.

I've used a lot of this type of simplistic SQL commands with no issue, I have no idea how to fix it nor do I have the knowledge how to build something that's more complex in nature - I'm a newbie so bear with me.

Comment: How are these tables related? Do both tables have a `columnnameY` and that's how you would join if just selecting? You still have to perform a join here (or at least a semi-join), but we can't tell you how to do that unless you tell us what to join on. Also please always prefix your columns so it's clear which table they come from! We can't see your schema so we have no idea.

Comment: My bad on the explaining part not adding more details, so they have only 1 column which shares the same informantion values, however they are with different column names, they dont have any other shared points apart of being in the same DB,
let me give u an example for my tables structure
so table 1 structure looks like this:
id - name - user id and few more meaningless columns
table 2 looks like this
id(just as counter) -type -char ID
the common link between these tables are ID from table 1 and char ID from table 2 in my statement above where i stated columnnamey='id' i was using 'type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the join criteria are because you haven't told us how X and Y are related, but a correlated join looks like this:

```
UPDATE x
  SET x.columnnameX = 'prefix' + x.columnnameX
  FROM dbo.tablenameX AS x
  INNER JOIN dbo.tablenameY AS y
  ON y.< ??? something ??? > = x.< ??? something ???>
  WHERE y.columnnameY = 'id';
```

Or like this:

```
UPDATE x
  SET x.columnnameX = 'prefix' + x.columnnameX   
  FROM dbo.tablenameX AS x
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tablenameY AS y
      WHERE columnnameY = 'id'
      AND y.< ??? something ??? > = x.< ??? something ???>
  );
```